# JSON.NET resolve nested interface list to concrete class

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a custom converter

```
public class ConcreteTypeConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then I have the following class's & interfaces

```
[DataContract]
public class Health : IHealth
{
    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "alerts")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<List<Alert>>))]
    public IList<IAlert> Alerts { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Alert : IAlert
{
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
public interface IAlert
{
    string Code { get; set; }
}
public interface IHealth
{
    string Status { get; set; }
    IList<IAlert> Alerts { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I get the converter to map the IList to List?

The current code throws

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xxx.Services.xxx.New.Alert]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[xxx.Services.xxx.Configuration.Model.New.IAlert]'.
```

Comment: You've "x-ed out" different parts of the namespaces of the `Alert` class in the exception message. Are they actually the same, or different?

Comment: They are different. The first is the concrete class and the next is the interface the concrete class inherits. Both of the are in two separate projects.

Comment: That's what I suspected. The link at the top of galenius answer explains why I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not the converter, it's the .Net type system. `List<Alert>` cannot be casted to `IList<IAlert>`, only to `IList<Alert>`, this is because `IList<T>` is not covariant ([see explanation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654060.aspx) and in other places).

What you could do, is writing a specified converter for your collection properties, which takes care of conversion between the collection item types:

```
public class ConcreteCollectionTypeConverter<TCollection, TItem, TBaseItem> : JsonConverter
    where TCollection : ICollection<TBaseItem>, new()
    where TItem : TBaseItem
{
    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var collection = new TCollection();
        var items = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<TItem>>(reader);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }

        return collection;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ICollection<TBaseItem>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Health : IHealth
{
    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "alerts")]
    [JsonConverter(
        typeof(ConcreteCollectionTypeConverter<List<IAlert>, Alert, IAlert>))]
    public IList<IAlert> Alerts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.  this custom converter fixed this exact same problem for me

Comment: Great solution, worked first time, unfortunately all other solutions failed me except this one.